# Google Photos API - authentication

Tags: api, google-photos

I'm trying to get list of my shared albums from Google Photos.
I found a enable Photos API in Google Developers Console.

HTTP GET:
https://content-photoslibrary.googleapis.com/v1/sharedAlbums?key=AIzaSyCkXXXXXXXXXXXXXZiOSe9IiyM8E

RESULT:

```
{ "error": { "code": 401, "message": "Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.", "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED" } } 1
```

Configuration in developers console:

[image]

Please, what I'm doing wrong? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Google API need an access token to make sure that the user has the permission to access the feature. Access token is just like cookie that should be send together with the request.

Usually you will need so many setup to get the access token with your own code. But there are a [client library](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/) that can help you access Google API with small setup.

Access token also has a lifetime, so if you don't use [the library](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/) you will need to manually refresh the token.

Comment: I am trying to fetch an access token and use the access token to call the google photos API. I am using googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token to fetch the token by passing grant_type, client_id, client_secret and refresh_token. This refresh token i got from going through oauth playground, so user consent got covered there. Now I get the access token from the API, with the correct scopes and expiry. When I use this token to call the Photos API, it says UNAUTHENTICATED. I really do not know what I am doing wrong. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure OAUth 2.0 credentials (client ID and secret) and not an API key. More details are in the developer documentation here: https://developers.google.com/photos/library/guides/get-started#request-id

The Google Photos library API acts on behalf of a user, that's why you need to authenticate via OAuth 2.0. As part of this request you also need to specify a scope for your users to accept, see this page for more details: https://developers.google.com/photos/library/guides/authentication-authorization

Comment: I am trying to fetch an access token and use the access token to call the google photos API. I am using googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token to fetch the token by passing grant_type, client_id, client_secret and refresh_token. This refresh token i got from going through oauth playground, so user consent got covered there. Now I get the access token from the API, with the correct scopes and expiry. When I use this token to call the Photos API, it says UNAUTHENTICATED. I really do not know what I am doing wrong. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I've been working on a python project to backup google photos library and album info. you can probably modify it to do exactly what you want. It is fully working but does not currently distinguish between shared and private albums.

https://github.com/gilesknap/gphotos-sync

In particular, see https://github.com/gilesknap/gphotos-sync/blob/master/gphotos/authorize.py which handles authentication and authorization for any Google service (it also handles storing the token and refreshing the token).

Comment: this is great, I'm writing the same exact thing in Java to backup my personal photos, and found this. I think I'll just give up on the java version :D. let's be honest, google documentation is the worst