# Authenticating Google Photos API with Service Account Key?

Tags: node.js, authentication, google-photos-api

Like this question, [Google Photos API - authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51943422/google-photos-api-authentication), I am curious about authentication for Google Photos API. One of the question's [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51943422/google-photos-api-authentication#answer-52175565) states that

> You need to configure OAUth 2.0 credentials (client ID and secret) and not an API key. More details are in the developer documentation here: https://developers.google.com/photos/library/guides/get-started#request-id
>
> The Google Photos library API acts on behalf of a user, that's why you need to authenticate via OAuth 2.0. As part of this request you also need to specify a scope for your users to accept, see this page for more details: https://developers.google.com/photos/library/guides/authentication-authorization

My problem is that I am trying to build a NodeJs-application that should serve another frontend application with images from google photos. I want to authenticate my backend application with a static "Service account key" (from https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials):
[image: from https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials]

I really can't find anyone who has done this before. That makes me think that I might be trying to build something impossible? The [google-api-nodejs-client](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client) does not support Photos API yet either.

**Question:**
If I log in to my google account and create a "Service account key" (I want my backend to feed my photos), would it be possible to authenticate to Photos API from my NodeJs-backend? How? (I'm not looking for a full solution, just a hint)

Answer (score 3):

Indeed nobody has done this before, because it is simply not supported by google:

In [this](https://developers.google.com/photos/library/guides/get-started) page about the google photos API, it is stated:

> The Library API does not support service accounts; to use this API, users must be signed in to a valid Google Account.